# How catch the classes in a code python Dynamically

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have a following code in python what represent a model of Data Base in sqlalchemy. Y want catch each class with its name and the atrr "**tablename**"

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Text, text
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.util.compat import ArgSpec
from common.utilities import Utilities

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata

class CcSipUser(Base,Utilities):
   __tablename__ = 'cc_sip_users'

   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   username = Column(String(80, u'utf8_spanish_ci'), nullable=False, server_default=text("''"))
   type = Column(String(6, u'utf8_bin'), nullable=False)
   amaflags = Column(String(13, u'utf8_bin'))
   call_limit = Column(Integer)
   callgroup = Column(String(10, u'utf8_bin'))
   callerid = Column(String(80, u'utf8_spanish_ci'))
   cancallforward = Column(String(3, u'utf8_bin'), 
class Post(Base):

   __tablename__ = 'post'

   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   title = Column(String(128, u'utf8_bin'))
   body = Column(Text(collation=u'utf8_bin'))


class Test(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'test'

   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   exten = Column(Integer)
   passw = Column(String(10, u'utf8_spanish_ci'))
   dis_name = Column(String(10, u'utf8_spanish_ci'))
```

Comment: Hello, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: This:                                                                                                     from models.models import *
from models import  *

table1 = CcSipUser()
table2 = Post()
table3 = Test()


print table1.__tablename__
print table2.__tablename__
print table3.__tablename__                                                                              But i know the name of class, and need don't know for code to do all.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your actual use case, you could do something awful like loop through the results of dir().

```
import models

for x in dir(models):
  try:
    print(getattr(models, x).__tablename__)
  except:
    continue
```

I believe that should work regardless of anything else.

Using metadata should also work, though the tables may need to have already been created.

```
from sqlalchemy import *

metadata = Metadata()

for x in metadata.sorted_tables:
  print(x.name)
```

That last example is straight from the documentation here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html

Comment: Fine, but no take the class to belong that table.

Comment: @NicolBolivar I have no idea what you said.